# Database.querylocater on external object in batch class not returning any rows

Tags: apex, batch, externalobjects, querylocator

I am writing a batch class on external object. Here I am using database.getQuerylocator in start method as the result will contain more thank 50k records.

Batch class code:

```
global class <batchclassname> implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    global String sQuery;
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
       sQuery = 'SELECT Id,....other field from <externalobject> ';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(sQuery);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {
//    
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    }
}
```

**Here in logs rows = -1**

Can anyone help me if there is any issue with the code or I need to do any other configuration?

**Note :** In external data source 
Server Driven Pagination = true
Request row count = true

Same code is working fine with Iterable. Since the records are more I can not use Iterable interface.

Comment: the below code is returning values in anonymous block:       String sQuery = 'SELECT Id,....other field from <externalobject> limit 1';
system.debug('result'+Database.getQueryLocator(sQuery));
system.debug(Database.getQueryLocator(sQuery));

Comment: Pretty sure query locators are only supported on the *Salesforce Database*.